# CoCreateInstance CLSID_IConverterSession fails with Office 2016

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm using IConverterSession to create mail items from mhtm files. This works fine with Outlook Versions < 2016. With Office 2016, IConverterSession cannot be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running C2R (click-to-run) version of Outlook 2016, all registry keys are virtualized - see the registry keys below (%s needs to be replaced by the Outlook version, e.g. `16.0`). Since the COM system does not look there, you will need to implement your own version of CoCreateInstance that reads the default value from the key to figure out the dll file name, then calls `LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress("DllGetClassObject") / DllGetClassObject(..., IID_IClassFactory, ...) / IClassFactory.CreateInstance`.

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\%s.0\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID\%s\InprocServer32
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\%s.0\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%s\InprocServer32
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID\%s\InprocServer32
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\%s\InprocServer32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've already managed to create an instance using DllGetClassObject and IClassFactory::CreateInstance. But: IConverterSession::MIMEtoMAPI does not work the way it used to do. The new message gets the source code of my MIME file as simple body text. Before Outlook 2016 it really created nice HTML messages. Any Ideas? Are there any new magic flags to set?

Comment: You might want to post a new question and provide all the necessary details. If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing CoCreateInstance() on your own, you have to enable registry redirection to enable C2R (click-to-run) virtualization of Outlook which is using detours to redirect the call to RegOpenKey(). After enabling that redirection just use the normal CoCreateInstance().

The reason why implementing CoCreateInstance() on your own doesn't work is, that the converter will also call CoCreateInstance() internally and that will fail like your original call because it doesn't find the CLSID in the normal hive of the registry.

I found out the code myself by looking on the jitv.dll exports. The parameters may be wrong, but as a first start it was working without a crash. To find out the parameters I have to debug an Office application and look at the disassembly (or any volunteers?).

Here the experimental code that worked for me :

```
HMODULE jitv = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT("jitv.dll"));
if (jitv) {
FARPROC efv  = ::GetProcAddress(jitv, "EnableFullVirtualization");
if(efv)
  efv();
  // call CoCreateInstance(guid::CLSID_IConverterSession)
  // and do your work
}

if (jitv)
  FreeLibrary(jitv);
```

There are some other exports in the jitv.dll whose names are mostly selfexplanary:

- "APIExportForDetours"
- "DisableVirtualizationOnThread"
- "EnableVirtualizationOnThread"
- "IsCurrentThreadVirtualized"

Thanks to [this posting](https://www.applepie.se/office-365-app-v-and-windows-10-1607) by nickekallen which mentioned that dll and brought me to that idea.